# SharePoint 2013 - How to mask a url within a content query web part

Tags: url, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, alias, documents

I am currently building a Sharepoint site in SharePoint 2013 that has sites for both internal and external purposes. The "internal" sites are accessible to our development teams, while the "external" sites are used to share content with clients and control their access.

I need to have the external sites display document / content lists that live in libraries either in the internal sites or their sub-sites. I am currently doing this through content query web parts. I am able to get things working functionally, but the URL of the displayed items exposes site structure and hierarchical information that I do not want to make visible to these external visitors.

Is there any way to mask or alias the URLs? The site's organizational structure must stay intact in order to maintain its permission inheritance. In essence, the external sites should act a landing page for our clients with the purposes of promoting collaboration.

Comment: Better suited to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you're talking about documents, not normal list elements, and you have SharePoint Standard at least, maybe activating Document IDs feature would hide the original url and show generated one. But it's only a guess, didn't test that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use short URLS or document IDs (for documents -  for lists see below). For short URLS:

https://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=short%20url&ac=4

Otherwise, you have a tedious task, involving code writing. Our solution was to write webparts for showing it and put in URL parameters the GUID of the list and the ID of the item. You could put the GUID of the (sub) site but the ulr will be too long (so what????).

Yet, exposing the structure of information wasn't our concern - our concern was the structured way of showing it.